# Import XML data into a PDF form using Python

Tags: python, xml, pdf

At my office we had PDFs designed using Adobe LiveCycle Designer that allows you to import xml data into the form to populate it. I would like to know if I could automate the process of importing the xml data into the form using python.

Ideally I would like it if I didn't have to re-create the form using python since the form itself is quite complex. I've looked up several different modules and they all seem to be able to read pdfs or create them from scratch, but not populate them.

Is there a python module out there that would have that kind of functionality?

Edit: I should mention that I don't have access to LiveCycle.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When posting questions, it is best to demonstrate a basic knowledge of the topic and post examples of what you have tried, or research you have completed to try and solve your own question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've changed my question with your recommendations in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is whether Adobe LiveCycle Designer support command-line arguments to do that. You could then automate this with python by issuing the command-line, hum, commands.

Comment: I personally don't have access to LiveCycle. Good thinking though.